# Upload to personal account with Dropbox API using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to make a small node app to upload folders and zip files to my personal Dropbox account. I need to put them in a specific folder, not the 'Apps' folder they mention in their documentation.

Is there a way to do this using the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://github.com/sintaxi/dbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use "Full Dropbox" permission. The details of the various app permissions are here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions.